# Counter for Specific Occurrences Within A Linked-List

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, counter

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

head = Node("Cat")
another_node = Node("Dog")
head.next = another_node
a_third_node = Node("Bird")
another_node.next = a_third_node
last_node = Node("Dog")
a_third_node.next = last_node

node = head   # copy the address of the head node into node
while node != None:
    print ("List item: ", node.data)
    node = node.next
```

For the code above, I get the following output:

```
>>> 
List item:  Cat
List item:  Dog
List item:  Bird
List item:  Dog
>>>
```

I need to include to this program a way to count the number of times a specific piece of data occurs within the list. So how can I create a counter that shows that "Dog" is in the list twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just increment a counter variable whenever you see given `value` instead of just printing the data:

```
def count(head, value):
    seen = 0
    while head is not None:
        if head.data == value:
            seen += 1
        head = head.next
    return seen

#...
print(count(head, "Dog"))
```